# Can I read route parameter's value from the `canActivate: AuthGuard`?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards, angular-route-guards

```
{
    path: ':l/bla/bla/bla', component: ..., canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}
```

Then `AuthGuard`'s constructor:

```
constructor(
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly activedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

... however both `.params` and `.snapshot.params` are empty and no `:l` parameter's value (shor for "language") can be read from there.

So question: how can I redirect to another page in case of unauthorized access, having my **dynamic** `:l` in place?

---

P.S. `data` does not work (does it?), since it is OKay for a compile-time known data rather than dynamic.

Comment: can you add whole `AuthGuard`?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45843291/4868839

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
canActivate(activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) { ... }
```

sovled the problem: method parameter should be prefered over constructor injection.