# Why queryparamshandling: "preserve" is not working as expected?

Tags: angular, angular-router

Friends, I am stuck with queryParamsHandling parameter that is not working as expected.
In my app i have a **redirect service** that is simply checking user role by using selector and depending on role redirects to specific urls. Code is below. What i want is just to save queryParams and redirect holding them on different route as well. I found out that queryParamsHandling is just for that. But it always flushes all queryParams on the redirected URL.
I want initial url like: ***http://main-page.com?param1=500*** after redirect to be **http://main-page-unauth.com?param1=500** still hold query param1. And that applied no matter how many queryParams is there - 1,2,3...1000

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable  } from 'rxjs';
import { select, Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import * as fromAuth from "../reducers";
import { map, take, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RedirectGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private store: Store<fromAuth.State>,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
  }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return this.store.pipe(
      select(fromAuth.selectRole),
      tap((role) => {
        if (role)
          this.router.navigate([state.url + '-' + role]).then()
        else 
           this.router.navigate([ '/main-unauth'], { queryparamshandling: 'preserve' })
            .then()
      }),
      take(1),
      map(() => true)
    )
  }
}
```

I even debugged that piece of code and can clearly see when queryparamshandling is being checked. In that moment currentUrlTree is always **null**.

```js
case 'preserve':
    q = this.currentUrlTree.queryParams;
    break;
```

How do i save queryParams and pass it to redirected URL? Thanks

**UPDATE:** queryparamshandling works as expected in components (when app is loaded). The problem is that i am trying to use it inside canActivate proccessing. How do i pass queryParams in this situation ?

Comment: while in same line of code i can get access to queryParams by just windows.location.search{href}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

queryParamsHandling is not working during canActivate guards. If you want to preserve queryParams you need to manually pass queryParams using ActivatedRouteSnapshot

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45843291/372212

Solution is working. And it also has an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a typo:

try to change

`this.router.navigate([ '/main-unauth', { queryparamshandling: 'preserve' } ])`

to

`this.router.navigate([ '/main-unauth' ], { queryparamshandling: 'preserve' } )`

Comment: thank you, its just a typo in example. I just remind that i pasted wrong code. Of course i tried correct way and all info in question related to correct code.

Comment: And what about the case? Do you have it like `queryParamsHandling`?

Comment: Yes, just double-checked, for sure, with camelCase. I have added and update in question head. Check it out

Comment: I had a similar situation when tried to use Route in service instead of a component. A route instance knows about current URL params only if it is injected into component that has to be shown in outlet when route gets resolved. Inside services it doesn't work.
Here's how I have solved it:
this.currentRouteParams$ = this.router.events.pipe(shareReplay(), filter(e => (e instanceof ActivationEnd) && (Object.keys(e.snapshot.params).length > 0)),map(e => e instanceof ActivationEnd ? e.snapshot.params : {}));

you can try this to get query params

Comment: Artem S. thank you for answer. I will try that as well. I've posted a little easier solution above